# I want to display the following json string into html table based on it's nodes. I am unable to do it. As i am new to json

Tags: c#, html, json

Json String is as follows:-

```
{
      d: {"lstname":
                  {
                     "Fname":"test",
                     "LName":"data"
                  },

            "lstAddress": 
                 {
                     "address1":"abc",
                     "address2":"def",
                     "pincode":"0",
                     "Area":"Bhandup"
                 }
       }
 }
```

**HTML Code**

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <%--<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />--%>
       <input type="button" name="btn1" id="Getdata" value="Getdata" />
        <div id="name">

        </div>
        <div id="Addess">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

lstname data should  be display in name div
and lstaddress data should be display in address div

Comment: so how your output look like?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
               $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "JsonDisplay.aspx/DisplayData",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { },
                   success: function (msg) {
                  var data = JSON.stringify(msg);
                       var jdata = JSON.parse(data);

                       var i = 0;
                  

                }
            })
            })

        })
    </script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed a bit your JSON - I have added "" to 'd:' property. So here the working version:
[In JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vLtqd6gm/)

```
var str = `{
  "d": {"lstname":
              {
                 "Fname":"test",
                 "LName":"data"
              },

        "lstAddress": 
             {
                 "address1":"abc",
                 "address2":"def",
                 "pincode":"0",
                 "Area":"Bhandup"
             }
   }


}`;
 var obj = JSON.parse(str);
 $(function(){
    $('#name').text(obj.d.lstname.Fname + ' ' + obj.d.lstname.LName)
  $('#Addess').text(obj.d.lstAddress.address1 + ' ' + obj.d.lstAddress.address2 + ' ' + obj.d.lstAddress.pincode + ' ' + obj.d.lstAddress.Area)
 });
```